# Fatal error: Call to a member function getLevel() on a non-object in list.phtml on line 44

Tags: magento

Fatal error: Call to a member function getLevel() on a non-object in list.phtml on line 44 
getting error at the time of seraching

```
<?php 
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count();



?>
<?php
$currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');
if($currentCat->getLevel()!=2){
if ( $currentCat->getParentId() == Mage::app()
->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() )
 {
    $loadCategory = $currentCat;
 }
 else
 {
    $loadCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->
  load($currentCat- >getParentId());
 }
 $subCategories = explode(',', $loadCategory->getChildren());
    echo '<ul class="subcategories">';
     foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId )
        {
            $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);

            if($cat->getIsActive())
            {
            echo '<li class="subicon"><a href="'.$cat->getURL().'">'
     .$cat->getName().'</a></li>';
            }
         }
         echo '</ul>';
 }else{
 $category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
 $categories = $category->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
?>
```

her is my code how this can be error free

Comment: Could you include all your code for list.phtml? Currently you have an error on line 44, but only 41 lines of code here.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you're using this list.phtml when not on a category listing page.

You'd be best doing a check to ensure the value you're retrieving is in the right format first.

```
$currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');
if (get_class($currentCat) == "Mage_Catalog_Model_Category"){
    if ($currentCat->getLevel() !=2 ){
```

This then ensures you have a Category object before you try to call a method on it.